# Python looping a dictionary multiple times

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

My issue is from a much larger program but I shrunk and dramatically simplified the specific problem for the purpose of this question.

I've used the dictreader method to create a dictionary from a csv file. I want to loop through the dictionary printing out its contents, which I can, but I want to do this multiple times.

The content of test.csv is simply one column with the numbers 1-3 and a header row called Number.

GetData is a class with a method called create_dict() that I wrote that creates and returns a dictionary from test.csv using csv.dictreader

My code is as follows:

```
dictionary = GetData('test.csv').create_dict()

for i in range(5):
    print("outer loop")
    for row in dictionary:
        print(row['Number'])


class GetData:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self._name = file

    def create_dict(self):
        data = csv.DictReader(open(self._name, 'r'), delimiter=",")
        return data
```

The output is as follows:

```
outer loop
1
2
3
outer loop
outer loop
outer loop
outer loop
```

My desired output is:

```
outer loop
1
2
3
outer loop
1
2
3
outer loop
1
2
3
outer loop
1
2
3
outer loop
1
2
3
```

Does anyone know why this happens in Python?

Comment: If you `print(dictionary)` in your code is it a generator, or an actual dictionary?  Possibly `dict(GetData('test.csv').create_dict())` if the former - generator expressions are consumed during iteration, while an actual dictionary would not be.

Comment: The output of `print(dictionary)` is `<csv.DictReader object at 0x0000000002223278>` which I suppose means I haven't actually created a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a file object, it's reading from the cursor position. This isn't a problem the first time through because the position is at the beginning of the file. After that, it's reading from the end of the file to the, well, end of the file.

I'm not sure how `GetData` works, but see if it has a `seek` command in which case:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('outer loop')
    dictionary.seek(0)
    for row in dictionary:
        print(row['Number'])
```

As g.d.d.c points out in a comment, it may also be a generator instead of a file object, in which case this approach is flawed. The generator will only run once, so you may have to `dict()` it. It all depends on how `GetData.create_dict` works!

As per your comment that `GetData.create_dict` gives you a `csv.DictReader`, your options are somewhat limited. Remember that the `DictReader` is essentially just a `list` of `dicts`, so you may be able to get away with:

```
list_of_dicts = [row for row in dictionary]
```

then you can iterate through the `list_of_dicts`

```
for i in range(5):
    print('outer loop')
    for row in list_of_dicts:
        print(row['Number'])
```

Answer (score 0):

csv.DictReader is an iterator for the associated open file. After one loop over the file, you're at the end (EOF).

To loop over it again, simply seek to the beginning of the file: `your_filehandle.seek(0)`